# Menu Drive Input Do Loop

Tags: c++

I need to create a Menu Driven Input [Case/Switch Statement] for my programming class. my professor didn't teach us how to create a menu yet and im having a hard time understanding my text book. I need the menu to loop until the user selects Quit to terminate the program. i also need a error message with the default in the Case/Switch, The error message must be descriptive of the error
caused by the user.

Can anyone guide me on what to do? I just need to get started and the rest usually comes naturally to me.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

ofstream ofs("bafia_lab5.txt");

string msg = "eofmessage ";
string cno = "blank ";
string name = "blank ";
string dat = "2/16/17 ";
string lab = "blank ";
string phn = "blank ";
string sum = "Create  menu that allows users to choose between While Loop, Do Loop, For Loop and quit. ";
string whlo = "While Loop:";
string dooo = "Do While Loop:";
string forro = "For While Loop";
int counter;
int option;

//Header for lab with name, class#, due date, and lab number
void hdr()
{
    ofs << name << cno << dat << lab << endl;
    ofs << endl;
}

void menu()
{
    do 
    {
        ofs << "1. Do Loop " << dooo << endl;
        ofs << "2. While Loop " << whlo << endl;
        ofs << "3. For Loop" << forro << endl;
        ofs << "4. Quit " << endl;
        ofs << endl;
    } while (option <= 4)
}


//Function for "while loop"
void whl()
{
    ofs << whlo << endl;
    counter = 1;

    while (counter <= 10)
    {
        ofs << counter << endl;
        counter++;
    }
    ofs << endl;
}

//Function for "do while loop"
void doo()
{
    ofs << dooo << endl;
    counter = 1;

    do
    {
        ofs << counter << endl;
        counter++;
    } while (counter <= 10);
    ofs << endl;
}

//Function for "for loop"
void forr()
{
    ofs << forro << endl;
    for (counter = 1; counter <= 10; counter++)
    {
        ofs << counter << endl;
    }
    ofs << endl;
}

//Function for description of lab
void ftr()
{
    ofs << sum << endl;
    ofs << endl;
}

//End of file function with name, class#, due date, and lab number
void eof()
{
    ofs << msg << name << cno << dat << lab << endl;
}

//Call all functions
int main()
{
    hdr();
    menu();
    whl();
    doo();
    forr();
    ftr();
    eof();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's a lot of junk in this question unrelated to the task at hand. What are all those strings for? Unless you're going to localize things, it's best to keep them as close as possible to where they're used. Also, as one of the most important things in programming is naming things, please **pick names that are descriptive**. `dooo` is not.

Comment: @tadman my professor makes use put everything in strings like that. i didnt come up with the names he did im sorry. whlo is for while loop void, dooo is for do loop and forro is for loop voids.

Comment: I just googled "switch statement menu c++" and there were tons of perfectly clear examples.  If you don't understand it from the textbook use other resources.  This is a basic concept.  Of course everyone has to start somewhere, but no one can convince you of how to do it better than you can.  It will be worth your time.  You should do that first then if you still have trouble come back and ask something.

Comment: It's unclear what the program is supposed to do other than that it is supposed to use a menu.

Comment: @polskiebmw Your professor isn't teaching very good coding style... Those single-line functions seem to just spread the program out, and you _really_ should put string literals right where they're used. There's no reason to put them at the top of the file like that; it greatly hinders readability. Also, don't be afraid to use entire words or short phrases as function names; readability is more important than brevity.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this :

```
char choice = 'y';
while(choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y'){
    cout << "Enter choice : ";
    cin >> choice;
    switch(choice) {
         case 'a' : cout << "This is case-a\n";
                    //do something
                    break;
         ...
         default : //invalid choice alert
                    break;
    }
    cout << "Enter y/Y to continue else anything else to exit : ";
    cin >> choice;
}
```